# Unhandled exception handler not called for Metro / WinRT UI async void event handler

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, async-await, c#-5.0

Consider the following to be extracts from a Windows 8 Metro / WinRT app, which have been reduced to the bare minimum required to show the anomaly:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) => e.Handled = true;
    }
}

public class MainPage : Page
{
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    private async void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

So given a Metro UI with two buttons and their click event handlers, the only difference is that the second event handler is marked as `async`.

Then clicking on each button, I would expect the UnhandledException handler to be called in **both** cases, since they (should) both be entered via the UI thread and associated synchronization context. 
My understanding is that, for `async void` methods, any exceptions should be captured and 'rethrown' (preserving the original stacktrace) via the initial synchronization context, which is also clearly stated in the [Async / Await FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx).

But the UnhandledException handler is **not** called in the `async` case, so the application crashes! Since this challenges what I consider an otherwise very intuitive model, I need to know why! Yes, I know I could wrap the body of the handler in a `try { } catch { }`, but my question is why isn't the backstop UnhandledException handler called?

To further emphasise why this doesn't make sense, consider the following practically identical extracts from a WPF app also using async / await and targeting .NET Framework 4.5:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        DispatcherUnhandledException += (sender, e) => e.Handled = true;
    }
}

public class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    private async void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

[There is a subtle difference that WPF has both an Application DispatcherUnhandledException event handler as well as an AppDomain UnhandledException event handler, but you can only mark the exception as 'handled' in the DispatcherUnhandledException, which aligns with the Metro / WinRT Application UnhandledException event handler above.]

Then clicking on each button, the DispatcherUnhandledException handler is indeed called in **both** cases, as expected, and the application does **not** crash.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix or workaround for this? I'm having exactly the same problem -- kind of a crippling issue with UnhandledException for logging errors.

Comment: Don't let the exception escape the `async void` event handler; i.e. wrap the body in a `try { } catch { }` block, or pass the body as a lambda to a helper function - that wraps the lambda to avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: Not an issue with Win 8.1's Application.UnhandledException event

Answer (score 5):

Answered here: [No UnhandledException fired from async event callback](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/bea154b0-08b0-4fdc-be31-058d9f5d1c4e)

It is a known limitation of WinRT. Hopefully, it gets fixed in the next update.

Comment: Thanks for the link Pierre. Unfortunately it doesn't have what I would call an answer. I also found [Application.UnhandledException can not capture the event](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/f434ddc7-351f-43c5-9535-0eab2048042a/), so I'm not alone in questioning this behaviour. A little birdy told me this was a known issue that didn't get fixed in time for release. I would really appreciate it if someone on the inside at Microsoft would answer / comment.

Comment: "this was a known issue that didn't get fixed in time for release". That's the answer, isn't it? What more would you want to know?

Comment: An indirect account from someone who knows someone etc, is just a rumor, not an answer. "I would really appreciate it if someone on the inside at Microsoft would answer / comment."

Comment: The answer in the link I gave comes from Matt Small at Microsoft.

Comment: But I don't see any 'answer' from Matt (an Escalation Engineer) at the link provided; just acknowledgement that the problem exists.

Answer (score 5):

The solution in the following post worked for me, with one small change: I had to move AsyncSynchronizationContext.Register(); to the App.OnLaunched event

http://www.markermetro.com/2013/01/technical/handling-unhandled-exceptions-with-asyncawait-on-windows-8-and-windows-phone-8/

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the documentation (source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception.aspx):

> It’s important to be aware of several limitations of the
>   Application.UnhandledException event.  This event is only used with
>   exceptions encountered by the XAML framework.  Exceptions encountered
>   by other Windows Runtime components or parts of the application that
>   are not connected to the XAML framework will not result in this event
>   being raised.
>
> For example, if a different Windows component calls
>   into application code and an exception is thrown and not caught, the
>   UnhandledException event won’t be raised.  If the application creates
>   a worker thread, and then raises an exception on the worker thread,
>   the UnhandledException event won’t be raised.

As pointed out in [this conversation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/bea154b0-08b0-4fdc-be31-058d9f5d1c4e), **only way to retrieve exceptions happening in a worker thread is to wrap them in a try/catch block**. As a consequence, here's the workaround I'm using in my app: instead of using `Task.Run` or equivalents to execute code on a worker thread from the UI, I'm using this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Runs code in a worker thread and retrieves a related exception if any.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="target">The target.</param>
/// <param name="action">The action.</param>
public static void SafeRun(this DependencyObject target, Action action)
{
    Task task = ThreadPool.RunAsync(o =>
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            /* Call the same error logging logic as in the UnhandledException event handler here. */
        }
    }).AsTask();
    task.Wait();
}
```

Bottom line is that to log all errors in your app, you should:

1. Subscribre to the *UnhandledException* event to get XAML stack related errors,
2. Wrap actions happening in a worker threads in a try/catch block.

Comment: I'm not creating any threads. The example `async void` event handler runs on the UI thread and associated synchronization context. Yes the *workaround* is to not let the exception escape, as already stated.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the only right answere was downvoted here (Try UnobservedTaskException event of TaskScheduler)

the problem is that you are using 'async void' where the exceptions cannot be handled. This is not a WinRT limitation but as design behaviour of async. You need to understand the async deeply to correctly implement exception handling here. See this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Exceptions are rethrown whe GC collects the tasks as unobserved. You can get them by registering TaskScheduler UnobservedTaskException event. Note - it takes some time till the exception arrives there, because it is noted with garbage collector.

Generally do not use 'async void', but in UI event handlers you have to, so this is thy only way..

Comment: Did you read the article you refer to? It says the same thing as my comment on Oct 23 '12: "With async void methods, **there is no Task object**, so any exceptions thrown out of an async void method will be **raised directly on the SynchronizationContext** that was active when the async void method started."

Comment: oops sorry, you are right! I tested it once again and the WinRT crashes immediatly. We are using Caliburn Micro, so I did not notice it firstly.. Maybe this could be a workaround: Caliburn accepts **async Task** event handlers and does exception logging, so this helps for all Click etc. events. Instead of **async void** handlers we use kind of FireAndForget-Trigger which starts methods (both sync and async) in background via Task.Run and takes care of exception handling.

Comment: we can now hope for a better future: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263110.aspx - see the part **"Surface all errors" feature** - it seems like they plan to handle the errors better.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old; nonetheless, a similar issue now plagues my UWP app.  Occasionally I must unwind the call stack by allowing an exception to propagate up it.  I need the exception to reach the app's `UnhandledException` handler, but that wasn't always happening.  This issue included the obvious case of throwing on a non-UI thread.  It also included a non-obvious case, the causality of which I have yet to pin down, of throwing on the UI thread.

I conjured up the below solution.  I catch the exception and then explicitly post it to the synchronization context.  Due to the strange aforementioned issue, I must do this even *while already running on the current synchronization context*. Otherwise, the exception sometimes doesn't reach the `UnhandledException` handler.

```
private void Throw( Exception exception )
{
    uiContext.Post( arg => throw exception, null );
    throw new OperationCanceledException();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try UnobservedTaskException event of TaskScheduler

Comment: `async void` does not use tasks. It uses the synchronization context. See the Async / Await FAQ.