# AppBarButton exception in Universal WinRT app not triggering unhandled exception event

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a Universal WinRT app and I'm trying to implement global exception handling so I can prompt the user to send me a report with extra diagnostic information I've collected.  (The extra diagnostic information is why I can't use the built-in handler that will log up to the Dev Portal).

I have the following code:

```
public App() {
    InitializeComponent();
    UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
    // other stuff
}

private void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
    try {
        //handler
    }
    catch { }
    throw e.Exception;
}
```

When I force an exception in my initial XAML page (my sign in page), e. g. hard code

```
throw new FileNotFoundException();
```

then my handler is triggered as expected.  However, if I do this in my main hub page, which my start page navigates to, then it looks like my handler doesn't run.  I can see the exception being thrown in the debugger, but it just gets swallowed somewhere.  I can't find out where.  I should mention that the app happily continues on at this point - it doesn't crash.

I've set `DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BINDING_DEBUG_OUTPUT` and `DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION` in my `Project Properties` to disable the built-in overrides, and as far as I know there's no `async void` situation here (e. g. [Unhandled exception handler not called for Metro / WinRT UI async void event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344357/unhandled-exception-handler-not-called-for-metro-winrt-ui-async-void-event-han) - although from what I've read, that kind of issue is resolved in 8.1 in any event).  But there may be some kind of hidden async void thing going on that I'm not seeing.

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid.  What is it?

(EDIT) It appears this is an issue when the exception is in a `AppBarButton` button event specifically.

(EDIT 2) A somewhat minimum repro is here: http://1drv.ms/1rSNq3i - run this in the 8.1 emulator or on an 8.1 phone, tap the button, open the commandbar, and choose `sign out` - this should trigger an exception and the handler, but the exception is lost.  If you move the code to a button in the same page (a standard button), the handler fires.

(EDIT 3) I tried using the dispatcher in a minimal way, and it didn't change the visible result:

```
private void SignOutAppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }).AsTask().Wait();
}
```

Comment: Can you share a small repro project? Is the problem on both phone and PC?

Comment: I haven't written the PC version at all yet.  I'll try to reproduce on a clean project.

Comment: Some exceptions are Native exceptions and are not caught by the managed code. You can't handle these exceptions unfortunately. They'll even crash your managed debugger if you have one attached.

Comment: Even a managed FileNotFoundException() like the one I list?  It works in a button, just not an AppBarButton in a CommandBar :(

Comment: If this is isolated to app bar buttons maybe you could try to run the click handling code on the dispatcher?

Comment: @FilipSkakun thank you for that suggestion - it didn't seem to help.  I added details to the question around this.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `UnhandledException` event you need to handle `Frame.NavigationFailed`. An exception in a page constructor results in firing `NavigationFailed`.