# Why the UnhandledException method does not trigger in Windows Phone 8.1 RT app?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

The UnhandledException method in WP8.1 RT app does not trigger at all. If an unhandled exception occurs, the app crashes right away. What could be the reason?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344357/unhandled-exception-handler-not-called-for-metro-winrt-ui-async-void-event-han) can help.

Comment: What code do you have that is crashing?